# How to pass a Arc with a trait as a reference?

Tags: rust, rust-clippy

How can I pass a reference to `Arc<A>` so that the following code compiles successfully?

```
use std::sync::Arc;

trait A {
    fn send(&self);
}

struct B;
impl A for B {
    fn send(&self) {
        println!("SENT");
    }
}

fn ss(a: &Arc<A>) {
    let aa = a.clone();
    aa.send();
}

fn main() {
    let a = Arc::new(B);
    ss(&a);
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=66edb1a002ecfbad5ef8ab9ad89708c1&version=stable))

If I omit the reference, it compiles okay, but Clippy warns me that in such situation in makes no sense.

Clippy error on the [code without reference](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d6afa260fbc924c1c1583e3fb8f233d0&version=stable):

```
  Compiling playground v0.0.1 (file:///playground)
warning: this argument is passed by value, but not consumed in the function body
  --> src/main.rs:13:10
   |
13 | fn ss(a: Arc<A>) {
   |          ^^^^^^ help: consider taking a reference instead: `&Arc<A>`
   |
   = note: #[warn(needless_pass_by_value)] on by default
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-clippy/v0.0.186/index.html#needless_pass_by_value
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the simplest fix is to *just ignore Clippy*.  Many of the lints in Clippy aren't in the base compiler specifically because they can be wrong or inapplicable.  Besides which, an `Arc` is already a kind of reference, and taking an `&Arc<_>` (or `&Rc<_>`) rarely makes much sense.

Secondly, as red75prime noted, you can change the function to take `&A` instead.

Finally, if you really want to appease Clippy, you could just do what it says:

```
fn main() {
    let a = Arc::new(B);
    { let a: Arc<A> = a.clone(); ss(&a); }
}
```

The reason you have to do it this way is that you can only coerce the "outermost" layer of indirection.  The `let` coerces the `Arc<B>` into an `Arc<A>`, then creates a pointer to it.

If there's some reason `ss` *needs* its argument to be an `Arc` (such as cloning it), just ignore Clippy or disable that lint.  If there's no reason `ss` *needs* its argument to be an `Arc` (you just need what's inside it), change `ss` to take `&A` instead.

That last one is mostly just for completeness.

Comment: I'd add to that next-to-last paragraph -- if `ss` *always* needs to clone the `Arc`, it should probably just take `Arc<A>` by value and let the caller decide whether a clone is necessary or not.

Answer (score 6):

You can pass a reference to an `Arc`'s content instead.

```
fn ss(a: &A) {
    a.send();
}

fn main() {
    let a = Arc::new(B);
    ss(&*a);
}
```